# How to put default value in preference page outside eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My need is to add some default value in preferences in my eclipse application. I have to do this outside my application, means when I launch my application the default value should be set in preferences.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the default values for the preferences based on some calculation you do before Eclipse is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default values for preferences are set via the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point. Here you should basically be able to read the preferences you have calculated outside Eclipse and set them using `IPreferenceStore.setDefault(...)`.

Comment: Is there any other way rather than doing it progrmmaticaly? Like putting some values in some properties file, which eclipse can read at runtime?

Comment: No, default values must be set programmatically.

Comment: I got some runtime options available here: [Runtime Otions](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) , here it is written about this option: **eclipse.pluginCustomization {-pluginCustomization}**
[the file system location of a properties file containing default settings for plug-in preferences. These default settings override default settings specified in the primary feature. Relative paths are interpreted relative to the current working directory for Eclipse itself.] Where this properties file is located?

Comment: Hmm, your right, but I usually don't recommend this, as this file is used for other things as well and it is usually placed side-by-side with eclipse.exe (or whatever) and therefore in the read-only area for the application.

Comment: Do you have any idea, where is this properties file located?

Comment: It is either specified via the option listed above or in the products extension point. By convention, it is normally put in the product plug-in with the name `plugin_customizations.ini`.